# Translating from cURL to straight HTTP requests

Tags: http, curl

What would the following cURL command look like as a generic (without cURL) http request?

```
feedUri="https://www.someservice.com/feeds\
  ?prettyprint=true"

curl $feedUri --silent \
  --header "GData-Version: 2"
```

For example how could such an http request be expressed in the browser address bar?  Partucluarly, how do I express the --header information if I were to just type out the plain http request?

Comment: This is not really a programming question and should probably be migrated to SuperUser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any browser that lets you specify header information in the address bar.  I believe there are plug-ins that let you do this, but I don't have any experience with them.

Here is one for firefox that looks promising:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/967

Basically what you want to do is not a standard browser feature.